# WMI commandline utility, console window host, and windows command processor all opening for a split second

Tags: malware, windows

Basically these 3 processes open for about 1/3 of a second and then instantly close on my task manager. I don't know what it is and I wasn't able to find anything on google about it. I am a little worried it might be malware but like I said I just don't know what it is.[image]

Comment: As much as I'd like to help, this is simply not enough information to work with. It's like going to a doctor, saying your brother complains that his neck hurts sometimes and expecting a diagnosis. We can't possibly tell you why this is happening or if it is malicious, at least not with any more certainty than a coin flip.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled WMI logging? If not enable it and check-in event viewer to read the queries executed in WMI. This will help to understand what WMI is trying to run. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/tracing-wmi-activity

If you have enabled `[audit process tracking][1]` using event ID 4688 you can find the caller process for WMI. This will help to understand which process is calling WMI.